# java.sql.SQLException: database is locked error

Tags: java, sqlite, connection

I'm in a situation where I get *Database is locked* on the statement:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement(cIQuery);
```

Where `pst` is `PreparedStatement` object and `conn` is the `Connection` object and `cIQuery` is the query which is going to be executed. However, I have closed all the `Connection`, `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` objects in each class after use. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the processes working on that database. You may be running your project multiple times and launching different processes as a result. So it may happen that some process is still alive and holding the database lock. Try checking the processes status using command

```
ps -eaf
```

Comment: @Neo Most of the operating system support this command. Simply open a command prompt and run this command.